# Not able to pass string as argument in c

Tags: c, string

I am trying to pass string as argument to a function. But the function is not calling. Please tell the mistake.

```
//Main calling
senddata("0000000000000001");   

// Function to call
void senddata(char message[])
{       
    if (sendto(s, message, strlen(message) , 0 , (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, slen) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("sendto() failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());             
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    fprintf(stderr, "Value of errno: %d\n", errno);
}
```

I have tried others methods also

```
void senddata(char* message);
```

or

```
void senddata(char message[16]);
```

But this function is call called.

please tell how to do

Comment: what happens when you try to call it?

Comment: How are `si_other` and `slen` defined and initialized?  Provide a compilable example that exhibits the problem.  Post the complete source code or at least the `main` function.

Comment: Do you have a prototype?  Do you have any warnings from your compilation?

Answer (score 0):

your function `void senddata(char message[])` expects a `char *` (or `char []`, which is basically the same), but you are calling it with a *constant* string, so it gets a `const char * message` (or `const char message[]`). You cannot convert a const to a non-const.

You need to either pass a variable (*non-const*):

`char * dummy = "0000000000000001";`
`senddata(dummy);`

or (probably the better way) declare the parameter as a const:

`void senddata(const char message[])`